# Check if user has been Logged In before loading anything else

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm making a simple reading canvas app, and I want to be ale to check if the user has been logged in before loading any of the content/articles. Naturally I have the FB.Init method, and I have a getLoginStatus within it, and it looks like this (I've removed my namespace and ID):

```
    <script> 
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {       
      FB.init(
      {
        appId   : '[APP ID]', // App ID
        status  : true, // check login status
        cookie  : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml   : true  // parse XFBML
      });

      FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {      
        if (!response.authResponse) {
         var oauth_url = 'http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/';
         oauth_url += '?client_id=[APP ID]';
         oauth_url += '&redirect_uri=' + encodeURIComponent('http://apps.facebook.com/[APP NAMESPACE]/');
         oauth_url += '&scope=read_stream,publish_stream,offline_access'
         window.top.location = oauth_url;
         }  
      });   

    };
    // Load the SDK Asynchronously
    (function(d){
      var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
      js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
      d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
    }(document));
</script>
```

But it no matter what I do, it loads my HTML content first (my Articles, Divs, Paragrafs, texts...) and redirects after finishing with that.

The script is the head od my HTML. I've also tried loading it through a onLoad() method in the body, but that didn't work either, it still loads some of my HTML content before redirecting.

How can I make it checked if the user is logged in to Facebook (and redirect if he's not), before loading even a single letter or image of the HTML code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using asynchronous loading of the facebook js sdk, and more than that, once you send the output back from the server (being static content or dynamic content) the browser gets the entire content and loads it, there's no much you can do about that.

If you want to check if the user is authenticated before then I advice you to use the [Server-Side auth flow](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/).
That way you can know the status before you even return the content to the user, if you discover that he's not authenticated then the content you send back to him is the redirection content.
Only when the user comes back authenticated will you send back the canvas content.

---

## Edit

If your entire app is static then keep it that way, no need to add php (or any other server side solution) just for server-side authentication.

I'm not exactly sure why you mind if the page is loaded before the redirect, here are two "solutions":

(1) Load a minimized page that has just the fb sdk and methods for checking if the user is logged in or not, if he is not then redirect him.
If he is logged in then load a script that adds the rest of the content and dynamically add it to the dom.

(2) In case that you just don't want the user to see something before he logs in, just make that part hidden with css and when he logs in change it using javasript.

Comment: Will I be able to do this via the JS SDK? All I'm seeing are PHP examples and snippets, and I'm not very efficient with PHP. 
If yes, could you give me an example of how to achieve this with JS?

Comment: No, you won't be able to use the js sdk, that's for client side usage only. You can find something to use with node.js for server side javascript, or write yourself since the sdk is just a facade for http requests. I've implemented in python (a few times) and java. What are you using in the server side?

Comment: My canvas app is completely HTML + JS (no php at all) at the moment, before you told me I wasn't even aware of the Server-Side authentication, and assumed the JS SDKs FB.login handled it too. Since it's working only with static HTML links (no data fetching), I didn't have a need for server side requests. So, I guess I'm using NOTHING in the server side...

Comment: Oh, I edited my answer since there was not enough space in the comment

Comment: Yeah, I already implemented option 2, with body.style = "none"; but some browsers have trouble with that one. Nonetheless, thank you.

Comment: Use a javascript framework such as jQuery that will take care of the cross browser issue for you.

Comment: I tried JQuery, but (.target).show() and (.target).css('display','block') both don't work with firefox, although every other browser is OK. I've tried it with body, but I read somewhere that it didn't work with body so I put everything in a div, still no dice. Even tried doing jQuery.noConflict(); and jQuery(document).ready(function($){}); and it didn't work.

Comment: If you'll supply a link I can check it out

Comment: I worked it out. It seems only Firefox was working CORRECTLY. I was calling FB.GetLoginStatus before FB.Init, and with Firefox it stopped loading when it got to that point, with the other browsers it skipped to the next step.